# Update scores in list view from array winjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-runtime, winjs

I have 4 scores in 4 arrays. I have to update it on every chance like this

Number of chances

```
1                      player1-1000    player2-150   player3-300   player4-40
2                      player1-500 player2-600 player3-650 player4-90
3                      player1-506 player2-900 player3-1000 player4-675
```

How to update the scores in listview winjs
arrays are score1, score2, score3, score4 for rescpective players!

I  have understood until this part

```
 var employees = [
  { name: "" + x }
    ]

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", { employees: employees });
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Can we see some more code here, especially what the inputs are, the expected outputs, and what the code is outputting now such that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it without the jQuery dependency (as I tend to do in Windows 8 apps), you can use something like...

```
scoreArrays.forEach(function(scoreArray) {
    scoreArray.forEach(function(score) {
        results.push(score);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are just trying to output the arrays in a more readable manner by player.  If you have a scores array like this:

```
var score1 = [1000, 150, 300, 40], score2 = [500, 600, 650, 90], score3 = [506, 900, 1000, 675], players = ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 4'], results = [0,0,0,0], scores = [score1, score2, score3];

$.each(scores, function(index, array){    
    $.each(array, function(i, v){
         results[i] += v;
    });
});

$.each(results, function(ind, val){
    results[ind] =  players[ind] + ': ' + val;
});

alert(results);
```

This will give you an array with player names and their accumulated score. Not sure if this was what you were looking for.